# Example of a specific $x^* \in X^*$ with $||x^*|| = 1$?

Tags: functional-analysis

We have $X \neq \{ 0 \}$ a real normed vector space and $||x^*|| = \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{|x^*(x)|_\mathbb{R}}{||x||_X}$. I was thinking of something like $x^*(x) = ||x||_X$ but this is not linear.

Is there any simple and specific $x^*$ (for a given $X$) we can write down with $||x^*|| = 1$?

Comment: You have to know something about $X$ before you can "write down" any linear functional at all, but once you have one, you can just rescale it to make its norm equal 1.  (There exist Banach spaces for which you need a non-constructive axiom of choice argument to prove that it has any linear functionals at all, e.g. $X = \ell^\infty / c_0$, and so you can't "write down" any of them.)

Comment: Ok I understand. Is it true that for every $X \neq 0$ there exists a non zero functional?

Comment: Yes, assuming some strong enough version of the axiom of choice; this is part of the Hahn-Banach theorem.